# React/Redux на странице выдает undefined добавленный массив в объект?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

есть такой код

```
export function fetchCategories() {
  return async dispatch => {
    dispatch(fetchCategoriesStart())
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('/api/category/categories')
      const categories = []
      categories.push(response.data.data)
      categories[0].forEach((category) => {
        axios.get('/api/product/findById/'+ category._id)
          .then(response => category.allProducts = response.data.products)

      })
      console.log(categories)
      dispatch(fetchCategoriesSuccess(categories))
    } catch (e) {
      dispatch(fetchCategoriesError(e))
    }
  }
}
```

При получении категории, делаю запрос по ИД категории и получаю массив продуктов, которые добавляю как массив к объекту Category. Однако когда в компоненте обращаюсь к state, allProducts нету. Не могу понять в чем причина

Comment: можно  пример вашего response.data.data. Там точно массив?

Comment: непонятно зачем categories[0].forEach вам это

Comment: @AzizUmarov Объект

Comment: А вы ожидаете массив и обращаетесь к нему как массив

Comment: Думаю проблема решится если про100 сделать categories.push(response.data)

Answer (score 1):

Думаю проблема у вас в этих местах. Должно быть так

```
categories.push(response.data);

categories.forEach
```